# Passing Data Between Main.storyboard and an XIB View (and vice versa)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

This may be a very simple question, but I have grown frustrated at being unable to find the answer (maybe I am not asking the right things?) I have, of course, found the answer when using Swift, but I use Objective-C.

Basically, I am struggling with passing data between the Main.storyboard and an XIB view. The buttons to present and dismiss the XIB view, located on the Main.storyboard, work fine. However, what I want to do is allow a switch, which is present on the XIB view, to alter a few things on the Main.storyboard. I have created an outlet for the switch on the XIBView.h, but obviously, to be expected, the Main.storyboard does not recognize the outlet (it is not linked in the viewController.h for the Main.storyboard).

Basically, what I'm asking, is how to allow the Main.storyboard to be aware of the switches active state (being on or off, located on a separate XIBView)?

I appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: I think you need is more information about `protocols` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: Also, remember that a xib is just a tool for building an object description, it is not an object by itself. You have to create an instance of an object from the xib. That object will have the switches which you can access from elsewhere.